# how to build libjpeg for ndk use

Tags: android, android-ndk, libjpeg, shared-libraries

I download libjpeg-8d source code. I want to compile it to libjpeg.so which could be used in android ndk. Because ndk use arm architecture, but the gcc of my PC is x86 architecture. So when I use gcc to compile out libjpeg.so and put it into jni folder. It shows file format can not recorgnize when use ndk-build. So how to build correct libjpeg.so for ndk?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find libjpeg 8d with an Android makefile here: https://github.com/folecr/jpeg8d

Alternatively, consider using libjpeg-turbo from `git://git.linaro.org/people/tomgall/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo.git`

Comment: thanks, and I put the source code into ndk, and compile it directly, it can also can work.